# Android textview visibility with recycle view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, visibility, android-viewholder

I have setup an application which populates a recycle view using information from an SQL database e.g. dates and times etc... I have recently setup a small section which either display or hide a textview depending on if the textview above it is the same or not. For example it will populate the first Textview with 13/06/2017 and make it visible, if the next date it wants to display is the same then it will simply hide the textview allowing multiple results with the same date to stack under each other.

**Problem**
My code is working as it should be and it stacking correctly. The problem I have is that when I scroll down the page and the up again all the headers disappear. This is caused by me not having correctly setup my viewHolder. Could you possibly give me some guidance on the situation.

**Bind View**

Code allowing the stacking of multiple duplicate results

```
if (position - 1 >= 0) {

String currentDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("complete_date"));

cursor.moveToPosition(position - 1 );

String previousDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("complete_date"));


 Log.i("storedDates", currentDate);    

 if (currentDate.equalsIgnoreCase(previousDate)) {

 txtHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 } else {


 txtHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 txtHeader.setText(currentDate);

 }

 } else {

 txtHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 txtHeader.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("complete_date")));
}
```

**Start ViewHolder**

```
public static class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

  TextView header;
  public Viewholder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);

       header = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
    }
}
```

**OncreateViewholder and OnBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext,mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent);

    return new Viewholder(view);



}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);




    mCursorAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());

}






@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursorAdapter.getCount();
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Use Model class and hold the data for hide and view.

Comment: So your saying to store the visibility of the textview in modal right? But how would the information be passed to model and no onclick occurs?

Comment: what is cardView in your code is it  header part ?

Comment: The textView sits within the Card View for that particular layout

Comment: so you missing cardView visibility with header in other conditions where you showing txtHeader

Comment: Nice spot Pavan completely missed that and went straight for the view holder. Could you post that as the answer and ill up vote it for you.

Comment: welcome @Steven added the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **cardView** visibility so where you setting  **txtHeader** visibility also set **cardView** visibility

```
    if (position - 1 >= 0) {

       String currentDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("complete_date"));

       cursor.moveToPosition(position - 1 );

       String previousDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("complete_date"));


       Log.i("storedDates", currentDate);    

       if (currentDate.equalsIgnoreCase(previousDate)) {

          txtHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

          cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          txtHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          txtHeader.setText(currentDate);

       }

     } else {
       cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       txtHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     txtHeader.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("complete_date")));
    }
```